# How to chop of blooger api content?

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am using blogger api. I get response for a post like this

```
<h4 style="text-align: left;">              <span style="font-family: Poppins;"><b>Chapter-1  “THE END OR A START?”</b></span></h4><h4 style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family: Poppins;"><b>&nbsp;</b></span></h4><h1 style="text-align: left;"><b><i><div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;"><a href="https://blogger.googleusercontent.com/img/b/R29vZ2xl/AVvXsEiApnHT6ldTH65AEU-Yi8eztBl4c0kD2KfLT8UP9qqf_k8oMcacZbdcDaUcuhDQXqhOQDVNPswymSmXiGH9qvKwD3JUiznA9b-X6-rXs0Z1awQACr7WGlmcFZJeIMmBSW_35Oa9h8UVbrkZhMqLTYoMAr0V9i_WyYHsWXva1sq0h0XOsS3e1i47om9byA/s1024/WhatsApp%20Image%202022-11-14%20at%2011.35.09%20PM.webp" style="clear: left; float: left; margin-bottom: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img border="0"
```

Its just a little bit of sample. I get a long content like this. Basically what I want to do is I want to display only some chunk of those response.
How can I chop off. I tried using `splice (0, 500)` but it is not displaying anything. How can I solve it?

Comment: Splice isn't working because you are chopping it in the middle of elements. Could you try adding all the elements to a container and then use javascript to remove the last few elements?

Comment: Yes I have added all of the content in a container. But how can I remove last few elements in js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the last element by using the removeChild() method. If you put that in a for loop you can choose how many elements you delete.

```
let div = document.getElementById('yourDiv')
let numberToDelete = 2;
for(i = 0; i < numberToDelete; i++){
     div.removeChild(div.lastElementChild);
}
```

This code should remove the last two elements from a div.